# Flutter - Add Progress bar or Shapes on image

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a widget where i can add a progress bar or shapes inside a image.

As in the attachment,

I wrapped the image and the shape inside the `Stack` widget but when the screen sizes change the position of the widgets change too

Is there any way to achieve this ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set the image as the decoration image of a `Container`. Then you can use a `FractionallySizedBox` for the item that should be placed inside the image, and set this widget as the `Container`'s child. You can also use a `Flex` and set the text and shape (the items inside the image) as its children.

```
Container(
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage(
                  'https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/151609/isolated/preview/1e5e087078b86c2491300c61ce46c48c-canning-jar-stroke-icon-by-vexels.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: FractionallySizedBox(
                heightFactor: 0.6,
                widthFactor: 0.6,
                child: Flex(
                  direction: Axis.vertical,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Flexible(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Container(
                          child: Text(
                        '50%',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                      )),
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      flex: 8,
                      child: Container(
                        child: Image.network(
                            'https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/129171/isolated/preview/c3746ad76845f55dda5e6a0d1c81d32a-3-stack-coins-icon-by-vexels.png'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Result:

[image: res]

Answer (score 0):

If you have screens size issue than use

```
double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
double  width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
```

you can get height or width of screen  and adjust view according to this.